# How to use awk to delete lines of file1 whose column 1 values exist in file2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, awk

Say we have file1.csv like this

```
"agvsad",314
"gregerg",413
"dfwer",53214
"fewf",344
```

and file2.csv like this

```
"dfwer"
"fewf"
```

how to use awk to delete those lines whose column 1 values exist in file2 and get a file3 looks like:

```
"agvsad",314
"gregerg",413
```

By the way I am dealing with millions of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++; next} !seen[$1]' file2.csv FS=, file1.csv` should do what you want but it will require enough memory to store an entry for each line in file2.csv.

Comment: Perhaps consider changing `$0` to `$1`, otherwise a single space somewhere in `file2.csv` may disturb the matching..

Comment: I used `$0` specifically to avoid problems with spaces in the quoted string in `file2.csv`. I assumed they would also exist in the quoted string in `file1.csv` and would want to be matched as whole units. `file1.csv` is parsed with `FS=,` so does not split on spaces (but `file2.csv` is parsed with the default value of `FS`).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, using grep:

```
$ grep -vf file2.csv file1.csv 
"agvsad",314
"gregerg",413
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works for smalle files but I am dealing with files with millions of lines. I run this and its still running is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: This will drop the lines no matter where the text occurs in the line. Though that might satisfy for this usage.

Comment: +1 for simple approach though it might be helpful to add `-Fw` options as well. I agree with caveat suggested by Etan. Only OP can confirm.